# Message: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager in PHP7.3 Codeigniter

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, codeigniter, php-7.3

I want to run mongo from PHP7.3 I am using MongoDB 64 bit, Xampp 64 bit, Apache Version:
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.13. I also added mongodb.dll extension in php.ini of PHP as well as in php.ini of apache.

On running the code below I am getting this error:

```
Message: Undefined property: MongoDB/Driver/Manager.:$tbl_food
```

User below code:

```
$pipeline = array();
$pipeline[]['$group']=array(
                        '_id'=>'$Product_Name',
                    );
$res = $this->mongo_db->aggregate_('tbl_food',$pipeline,['allowDiskUse' => TRUE]);
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

Comment: The error message should be included in the question as text, not as an image. That way it will show on search and members seeking to help you can simply copy paste the error message at their leisure. Please consider: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Hi, @bad_coder my bad, I have updated question as per you says. removed the image and add an error message as a text. can you please help me solve this issue.

Comment: I commented on your question because I came across it on the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review). Basically I pointed out the method that applies to all questions on stackoverflow. I'm not fluent in coding with php, but I hope another member will help you out.

Comment: **BTW** thanks for suggest